# Generalized functions in infinite dimensions

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, infinite-dimensional-manifolds, generalized-functions

What theories are there for generalized functions (distributions) in infinite dimensions?

In particular, suppose your "infinite dimensional manifold" is $\mathfrak{M}:=C^\infty(S^1)$. Is there a theory of generalized functions based on the test functions which would roughly be smooth functions on $\mathfrak{M}$?  Perhaps using the convenient calculus of Kriegl/Michor.

Answer (score 6):

The study of an "infinite-dimensional delta function" has been motivated to a large extent by applications in quantum field theory. Here is some relevant literature:

- Tempered distributions in infinitely many dimensions, [part I](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01646305), [part II](https://www.mscand.dk/article/view/10713), and [part III](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01646321) (1964-1967)
- [Functional delta-functions and Fourier transforms](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0305-4470/17/6/014)
   (1984)
- [Generalized Functions in Infinite Dimensional Analysis](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0211196) (2002)
- [Recent Results in Infinite Dimensional Analysis and Applications to Feynman Integrals](https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0302066) (2003)

Comment: Nagaev's notes are about probability distributions, mainly on Banach spaces, whereas the question is about generalized functions on "infinite dimensional manifolds" (rather than the usual generalized functions on $\mathbb R^n$). Of course, any probability distribution on $\mathbb R^n$ is a generalized function, but not vice versa, and the subject of the theory of generalized functions is very different from that of the theory of probability distributions.

Comment: my mistake, thank you for correcting me; I deleted Nagaev and added further references.

Comment: I have two points of confusion, here. 
1. Is it possible to see the usual distributions on $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a special case of this theory? When I try, the test functions seem to be analytic instead of smooth, but perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: 2. The distributions seem to be functions of duals of nuclear spaces, so in my example above, this would be functions of $\mathscr{D}'(S^1)$, instead of $\mathscr{D}(S^1)$. So if one has a partial differential operator acting on smooth functions of $\mathscr{D}(S^1)$, it doesn't seem to necessarily extend to the "distributions". Is that correct?